# How can I prevent a jQuery Mobile popup from closing when clicking on a link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, hyperlink, click, hashchange

I'm trying to combine a jQuery Mobile [popup](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/) with links inside using the `:target` pseudo-selector.

It works well in theory (`click element, hashChanges, change CSS using :target`), but either the click or (more likely) the hashChange also closes the popup.

Here is a quick example of a popup that flips on click.

```
/* =========================== FLIP popup ========================= */
.ui-popup .card_register {
  display:none;
}
#access-popup:target .card_login {
  display:none;
}
#access-popup:target .card_register {
  display:block;
}
@media screen an
  (min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  .ui-popup-container {
    perspective: 800;
  }
  #access-popup:target .ui-popup {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  .ui-popup {
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .card_login, .card_register {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .card_register {
    position: relative;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  #access-popup:target .card_register,
  #access-popup:target .card_login {
    display:block;
  }
}
.ui-popup-container {
  max-height: 400px;
}
.ui-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
.card_login, .card_register {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card_login {
  height: 400px;
}
.card_register {
  bottom: 400px;
  float: left;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
  <a href="#access" data-transition="pop" data-rel="popup">Open</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="access">
      <div class="card_login">
        <a href="#access-popup" rel="external">Register</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card_register">
        <a href="#&ui-state=dialog" rel="external">Login</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The flip transition and fallback work allright on `:hover` but when I try to use the `:target` selector, every time I click the link, the popup closes.

**Question:**
I know I could bind to `popupbeforeclose` and `preventDefault` but I would like to know, if there is a default way to prevent a popup from closing when a link inside a popup is clicked? I have tried `data-dismissable="false"` and setting `rel="external"` on the link. Both did not work.

Thanks for inputs!

Comment: You could also stop the click event's propagation sth. like `$('[data-role="popup"] a').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});` I guess.

Comment: true, there is a few ways stopping it with jQuery or Javascript, but I'm still hoping for a "hardcodeable" solution (excluding Javascript). Thanks so far

Comment: Do you go to a new page once link is clicked?

Comment: no. the popup "slides out to the top", which I have not defined anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baring a better answer, this seems to be the "least-invasive" JQM way to prevent the popup from closing:

```
  $(window).on('navigate', function(e, data) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

still needs tempering as to when to really `preventDefault` and when to let the event pass.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an onclick function like this worked for me:

```
onclick="return !window.open(this.href)"
```